# How can i set expandablelistview with linearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, expandablelistview, tablelayout

In my android application,I have an Expandable list view and a button in tableLayout but i have a problem, width of table in not show completely, i set (android:layout_width="match_parent") but it does not work.On the other when i using the linearLayout, the button hides under the list (when i open a sublist). some kind of overlap between items. I have 2 item over each other. one of them is hiding under other. how can i fix it?

my code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/expandableListView"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/backup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="BackUp"
                android:clickable="true"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use attribute `layout_weight` in children of LinearLayout. It shows how much space do they get on screen, so if you set `layout_weight` to only one view in LinearLayout this view would take all free space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backup"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BackUp"
        android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```